# How to pass an Intent extra from the Intent View Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm using a `AdapterView` for a `ListView`, the activity where we can find the list view and an `EditText`.

When we click on one element of the `ListView` we go to the second activity, and I want to send the data of the selected item as an extra in a `intent`.This data will then be shown in the `EditText`

I tried this code, but it doesn't seem to work, it shows always the default value of the `EditText`.

here is the code of the adapter view :

```
public class adapterq extends ArrayAdapter<Questionaire> implements OnClickListener {
    Bitmap image;
      EditText name;

    public adapterq(Context context, ArrayList<Questionaire> questionaires) {
       super(context, 0, questionaires);
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
       // Get the data item for this position
       final Questionaire c = getItem(position);    
       // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
       if (convertView == null) {
          convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customquest, parent, false);
       }

     View  convertView2 = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);


       TextView q = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
 name =     (EditText) convertView2.findViewById(R.id.editText1);


       q.setText(c.getLabel()); 

       convertView.setOnClickListener(this);

       return convertView;
   }
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();

            intent.setClass(getContext(), Questions.class);

        intent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
            getContext().startActivity(intent);  

    }


}
```

here is the xml code of the main activity :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"

tools:context="com.example.orange.v1.MainActivity" >

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_width="270dp"
    android:layout_height="250dp"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
     android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp" >

</ListView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="18dp"

    android:text="User Identifier :"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView2"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:text="Yass"
    android:ems="10" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="36dp"
    android:text="Questionaire Choice"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_below="@+id/listView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
    android:text="Select a category to start playing" />
```

With a screenshot of the view :

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> How to pass an Intent extra from the Intent View Android

Because `EditText` is inside convertView2 layout but click listener is in `convertView` do it as:

```
q.setText(c.getLabel()); 
convertView.setOnClickListener(this);
convertView.setTag(convertView2);
```

Use `v`  parameter of `onClick` method to get clicked `EditText` value:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
          Intent intent = new Intent();
          intent.setClass(getContext(), Questions.class);
          View view=(View)v.getTag();
          EditText edtName=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
          intent.putExtra("name", edtName.getText().toString());
           getContext().startActivity(intent);  

    }
```

Comment: I'm getting an error when executing NullPointerException

Comment: @Strange90: see my edit answer now it will work. previous logic not working because EditText is inside `convertView2` but click listener for `convertView` then onClick method view parameter returning `convertView` instead of convertView2

Comment: No Error, but Always it passes the default text in EditText

Comment: @Strange90: why you are using two layouts ?

Comment: @Strange90: see following example [Android Listview with multiple row layout](http://www.survivingwithandroid.com/2014/08/android-listview-with-multiple-row.html) to use multiple layouts for ListView rows

Comment: I don't have another choice, this is an adapter view the first layout is for the list view, and the second is the layout of the mainActivity, anyway `EditText edtName=(EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.editText1); `  View must be v ?

Comment: @Strange90, share the screenshot of the view rendered. Maybe there is some other issue...

Answer (score 1):

update your code as follows:

```
public class adapterq extends ArrayAdapter<Questionaire> implements OnClickListener {
Bitmap image;
EditText name;

public adapterq(Context context, ArrayList<Questionaire> questionaires, EditText name) {
   super(context, 0, questionaires);
   this.name=name;
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
   // Get the data item for this position
   final Questionaire c = getItem(position);    
   // Check if an existing view is being reused, otherwise inflate the view
   if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.customquest, parent, false);
   }

 TextView q = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);


   q.setText(c.getLabel()); 

   convertView.setOnClickListener(this);

   return convertView;
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      Intent intent = new Intent();

        intent.setClass(getContext(), Questions.class);

    intent.putExtra("name", name.getText().toString());
        getContext().startActivity(intent);  

}
```

}

and pass the instance of name while initializing the arrayAdapter

Comment: Hmm just say declare `EditText name` as `final` instead of posting whole code

Comment: I wouldn't be able to access the EditText name from the onClick function, Thanks

Comment: It always pass the default text of the EditText

Comment: Thank's, but always the same problem it takes the default value if EditText